# Show a inequality by maximum principle .

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

As below picture ,how to get the inequality 3 by inequality 1 and 2 ? It seem relate to PDE, but  when I use the maximum principle ,  I don't know how to deal the $-F^2$ .

Maybe, this question is fuzzy, so ,you can find detail describe in 196th page in this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: You can control the $F^2$ by comparing to the ODE $F'(t) = -F^2 + M^2$. See e.g. Hopper+Andrews theorem 6.4.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   it seem to use the theorem 6.15 ? but I really don't know how to do it .

Comment: @John Ma  Help me !

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   It's really beyond my ability ,Could you give a detail answer ? Thanks very much.

Comment: @lanse7pty: It's just a scalar function, so it only needs the scalar maximum principle 6.4. Apply it to the operator $Lu = \partial_t u - \Delta u + u^2 - M^2$ and the function $u=-F$.

Comment: If it's beyond your ability then so is the entire paper you're trying to read. It's a straightforward application of the theorem.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Is it 6.4 of $\frac{1}{4}$ pinching ? I think it need to get $F\le H \forall t$, it seem not study $F$ alone.  I am very sorry. I want to read it detail , but I must report this to my teacher .

Comment: Maybe $\partial_t (F-H) \le \Delta(F-H) - (F-H)(F+H)$ is the easiest place to start - this tells you $F<H$ is preserved.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   I think I finish it . if $F>H,then, \partial _t(F-H)-\Delta(F-H)<0,$ because $H,F>0$, and the manifold is compact ,so ,$F-H$can reach the maximum at t =0.but ,when $t=0$, $F-H<0$,so $F<H,\forall t$ ,it's contradictious with  $F>H$. Am I right?

Comment: but ,there are some question , the $B_0(p,r)$ has boundary , maybe the maximum reach on the $\partial B_0(p,r)\times t$